# Extract data over a threshold

Tags: matlab

So if I have a 2000 x 4 matrix, where row 1 is a time stamp, row 2-4 is data for different variables.

What I'm looking to do is extract data from one one variable (say column 2) is over a certain threshold, however I want to extract the previous 100 samples and the next 100 samples from when the value goes back below the threshold again.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting if a value is over a threshold:

```
overThresh=sampleMatrix(:,columnOfInterest)>threshold;
```

This creates a logical column vector with the same length as your matrix, with 'true' indicating elements that are bigger than your threshold.

Now to expand these regions by 100 samples, I will use a trick from image processing: image dilation:

```
SE = strel('arbitrary', ones(100,1))
extractVector=imdilate(overThresh,SE)
```

Now extractVector is true for the samples you want (over threshold + 100 next to them).

```
interestingSamples=sampleMatrix(extractVector,:)
```

This gives you a matrix with the values of all columns, but only the rows you are interested in.

Edit:
You can assign labels (integers) to each event of threshold violation, using:

```
overthreshLabeled=bwlabel(overthresh);
```

Now each region will consist of a number instead of "true's". With each number corresponding to a specific region of adjacent events of going over the threshold.
You can then loop through the region numbers and extract the values, and put them all in a cell (it has to be a cell because they can have different lengths).

```
ROIs{1,max(labeledThreshold)}=[]; % preallocation

for i=1:max(labeledThreshold)
    region=labeledThreshold==i;
    extractVector=imdilate(overThresh,SE) % Note: set SE before loop
    ROIs{1,i}=sampleMatrix(extractVector,:)
end
```

Comment: Great, this does everything I asked for. Now if I was to expand say I had the same sample matrix and have 2 separate incidents that violate the threshold. How would I be able to extract both events as separate matrices?

Comment: edit: I will just update the answer to get proper code markup

Comment: So my code is now this. 

`overThresh_high = Data(:,3) > 50.2;
overthreshLabeled=bwlabel(overThresh_high);
SE_high = strel('arbitrary', ones(3000,1));
ROIs{1,max(overthreshLabeled)}=[]; % preallocation

for i=1:max(overthreshLabeled)
    region=overthreshLabeled==i;
    extractVector=imdilate(overThresh_high,SE_high); % Note: set SE before loop
    ROIs{1,i}=Data(extractVector,:);
end`

Comment: This is still giving me both events combined

Comment: Would you like to consider multiple events at consecutive timepoints (with no points in between) to be 1 event with a certain duration (which is what the code is supposed to do now) or rather treat them as separate events?
The latter would result in extracting almost the same data multiple times (with the roi one time point shifted).
If the code does not behave as expected, you might need to execute it line by line and see where the mistake is...

Comment: What I'm looking to consider that if a threshold has been violated for a certain number of points I want that to be considered as one event. So I was thinking the best way was to use the time stamp? Because if the time stamp doesn't increase linearly in the extracted data then there is multiple events in the extracted data.

Comment: What I'm necessarily trying to do is to detect the violation of a threshold, extract 100 samples before and after events (the end of the event being when the samples drop below the threshold again), store and save individual events. As I said in my previous comment I think the easiest way to do this is to look at the time stamp as this will change the most if a threshold violation hasn't occurred in a while